# Why does login dialog not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to allow this website to login via AJAX but whenever I click the `submit` button nothing happens. Here's the code thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var user, pass;
 
 function login(usrnm, pwd) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'login.php?username=' + usrnm + '&password=' + pwd,
   type: 'POST',
   data: undefined,
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function (result) {
    alert(result);
   },
   error: function () {
    throw new Error("Error processing AJAX on function login().");
   }
  });
 }
 
 $("#bgFader").hide();
 
 $("#login").click(function() {
  $("#bgFader").show();
  
  jQuery("<div/>", {
   id: "loginBox",
  }).appendTo("body");
  
  $("#loginBox").html(
   '<span id = "loginBoxTitle">Login</span><br>'
   + '<input type = "text" placeholder = "Username" id = "username"><br><br>'
   + '<input type = "password" placeholder = "Password" id = "pwd"><br><br>'
   + '<button id = "submitBttn">Submit</button>'
  );
  
  $("#loginBox").center();
 });
 
 $("#bgFader").click(function() {
  $("#loginBox").remove();
  
  $("#bgFader").hide();
 });
 
 $("#submitBttn").click(function() {
  user = $("#username").val();
  pass = $("#pwd").val();
  login(user, pass);
 });
 
});
```

```css
#bgFader {
 opacity: 0.75;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: black;
}

#loginBox {
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
 padding: 10px;
}

#loginBoxTitle {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang = "en">
 <head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <title title = "">
   
  </title>
  <link rel = "apple-touch-icon" href = "">
  <link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://www.gigaboywebdesigns.com/GigaboyJS/Gigaboy1.3.3.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id = "login">Login</button>
  
  <div id = "bgFader">&nbsp;</div>
 </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Your submit button doesn't exist when you do `$('#submitBttn').click...`, so no click handler gets attached when you do finally insert the button's html.

Answer (score 1):

Change the id of the button to `submitBttn`

`<button id="submitBttn">Login</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Post method should be like this

```
 $(function () {
            login('userName', 'Password');

            function login(usrnm, pwd) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.username = usrnm;
                obj.password = pwd;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Login.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        throw new Error("Error processing AJAX on function login().");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

although i tested it with asp.net web form ...but its should be fine with php also ..Your request is get formatted convert it to post

Answer (score 0):

You add a click handler to your future submit button before you add the submit button to DOM on `login` button click.

Should have:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitBttn', function() {
    user = $("#username").val();
    pass = $("#pwd").val();
    login(user, pass);
});
```

instead of

```
$("#submitBttn").click(function() {
    user = $("#username").val();
    pass = $("#pwd").val();
    login(user, pass);
});
```